# Angular Same Directive for Slightly Different Partials?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, code-reuse, reusability

I'm building a web app that has the same layout pattern used over and over, however some parts of the app are slightly different. Part of me feels I could wrap these all into the same directive but I'm not sure how to accomplish this.

The bulk of the app is just a table with an ng-repeat. Above the table is a date picker and some `<select>` elements used for filtering the results and requesting them from the server.

The differences between the pages are:

- One table has 7 columns, the others have 8
- One filter section has a search box
- One filter section has two different `<selects>` the other has just one
- All tables query different api endpoints
- The headings of the tables are all completely different.

Part of me thinks I could rewrite these into one reusable piece of code, I'm just not sure how to go about doing it. Any helps is really appreciated!

Comment: You can easily customize the template that a directive uses by using `ng-include`.  See [this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/uaC4Vcs3IgirChSOrfSL?p=info) that I did for a previous answer.

Comment: Yeah I know how to write directives that link to a template file. The question was I want to write one versatile directive that can handle a table with subtly varying amounts of columns and subtly varying <select> elements. The answer I'm looking for is more related to dynamically generating tables or using conditionals in directive templates I believe.